# Remotely control folder access on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, remote

I'm looking for a way to remotely control the access to a specific folder on a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

This access needs to be changed regularly, so it has to be easy to change. Working with a third-party software would also work, but I haven't found any network file sharing software yet that can restrict access to a folder on the Raspberry Pi. It's supposed to be user-friendly and accessible with graphical user interface.

Comment: You tagged the question with [tag:ssh]. What is wrong with logging in with SSH (from a remote location) and changing the directory permission with `chmod` and/or `chown`? Is that not what you are asking for? In essence a single command, `ssh user@host chmod 700 /dir/path`.

Comment: What kind of network sharing are you thinking of? Samba? NFS? Something like `rsync` over `ssh`? `sshfs`? FTP? SFTP? WebDAV? Something else?

Comment: Simply using SSH would work, but it is not ideal in my case, as it's supposed to be user-friendly and accessible with graphical user interface. The kind of network sharing tool is subordinated.

Comment: I think you should remove the ssh tag. This isn't about a problem with ssh, it's just about something you're doing while sshed in. The problem you're trying to solve could just as easily be a problem with a local machine where you are physically logged in. Analogy: if you want help with the `find` or `grep` command while sshed in, you also wouldn't add the ssh tag just because of your specific login method.

Comment: You said the access needs to be changed regularly - changed how? Is there a fixed set of possible access settings, or is it a simple on/off, or something more complex? What kind of access are we talking about - will the users be logging in locally, or accessing this through a SMB (=Windows) or NFS share? A very common way is to create a user group and grant that group access to the folder, and then add/remove users to the group as needed - if that works for you, then you'll need a graphical group membership management utility.